# SQLAlchemy: Structuring 3 way recursive one-to-many relationships between 2 (two) tables

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Synopsis:

Working with a relational database (ex: SQLite),
I have `two tables` where `two object types` are mapped respectively.
Let's call these tables `table_a`, `table_b` and object classes `A` and `B`.

The desired design:

Objects instantiated from class A (ex: a_1) can have one or more B objects:

```
Ex: a_1.bs = [b_1, b_2, b_3]
```

Objects instantiated from class B (ex: b_1) can have one or more A objects:

```
Ex: b_1.as = [a_8, a_9, a_11]
```

Again, B objects should also have *the* "backref" from the first relationship to its parent of type A:

```
Ex: b_1.a = [a_1]
```

Also, if an A object (ex: a_8) is one of a type B instance's `a`, then it should have the backref:

```
Ex: a_8.b = [b_1]
```

As you can see, there are 2 tables but they are infinitely connected.

So:

```
A can have one or more Bs and each one of those Bs can have one or more As.
```

I tried various options from SQLAlchemy **ORM** documentation however I am, due to lack of experience and complexity of the situation, at a lost.

What do I need to do in order to obtain this result?

Thank you.

Comment: If I get that right, you have multiple items in both directions (essentially a `many-to-many`) but you also have a primary item? Is this primary item then bidirectional, i.e. `b_1.a.b == b_1`?

Comment: a1.bs = [b1, b2, b3 ..] | b1.a = a1 | b1.as = [aX, aY ..] | b1.a.b == unknown.. I think I need to associative tables without backrefs.